# What kind of email services should one use for online accounts such as paypal, adsense, youtube…?

Tags: email

Is using gmail accounts safe for your online accounts or should I employ some kind of encrypted email? I'm not paranoid, I just seek an opinion from someone who knows what they are talking about...

In 2014 I was living with a friend who was at that time an objectively gifted programmer but he went to India and literally left his phone home on purpose. (I can't ask him now) He told me he could hack a gmail account in a matter of 30 minutes if I remember correctly, and while I don't know or care if that is good or not, it leaves me uncertain about gmail...

I know absolute security is a myth, but what kind of email services should one employ to have reasonably good security for their online accounts

Comment: You might have been better asking this on https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `He told me he could hack a gmail account in a matter of 30 minutes` most likely he didn't use a flaw in GMail, but rather he found that most passwords out there are ridiculously easy to guess. A simple dictionary attack breaks into *any* email account in a matter of minutes if the password is weak.

Answer (score -1):

I use outlook.com for this logging in purposes. I have kept my official mail away from these cause they are after all third party and might end up selling their domain to someone. Information at stake should never be an option.

First of all, it belongs to Microsoft. An assurance in itself to find it much more secured.

Secondly- there are lesser chances of receiving spam emails. At least I haven't received much until I really subscribed them. In Gmail, I still receive spam emails and all don't know why even though I don't use it for logins. Probably Microsoft has got better spam filters.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Let me ask you - do you know in what way is outlook.com more safe than gmail?

Comment: I take strong exception to the idea that Microsoft products are secure. try floating that idea on https://security.stackexchange.com/, or even just Googling for something like "how secure are Microsoft products". Generally speaking, they leak like a sieve.

Comment: Google's main business is data. So any detail you give them, they will use. MS isn't any better, seeing the "privacy nightmare" they've created with Windows 10. I wouldn't trust any of the two with any of my data. No, Yahoo neither of course. If you want a secure mail provider, those are at the very end of the list. Especially if you share the opinion that your data are yours.

Comment: *comment by [Mawg](/users/3397/mawg) (moved from Jennifer's second answer now integrated here):* the computer literate here are laughing out loud at that "belongs to Microsoft. an assurance in itself to find it much more secured" - unless you are (correctly) recommending to find some thing much more secured than Microsoft

Comment: One more guy laughing at the security of Microsoft.  Personally I run my own server, each company I do business with gets their own address.